# Can creatures use Grab on a Charge attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, grapple, combat-maneuver, charge

My reefclaws are attacking the players underwater. They [charge](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#charge) the oracle/monk. [Reefclaws](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/reefclaw.html) have Grab and [2 Claw](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/universalMonsterRules.html#natural_attacks) attacks. If I charged, am I correct in thinking that:

The reefclaw would get one claw attack at the end of the charge, and if it hit, a chance to grapple with the [Grab](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/universalMonsterRules.html#grab) ability?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question's answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/82825/8610), some examples therein (*ahem*) tackling this issue. Also, what's the monk/oracle's size category?

Comment: @HeyICanChan medium

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, they can

[Grab](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Grab_Ex) special ability says:

> If a creature with this special attack **hits with the indicated attack** (usually a claw or bite attack), it deals normal damage and attempts to start a grapple as a **free action** without provoking an attack of opportunity.

Not only that, but they can make a free grapple whenever they successfully make an attack with that weapon, regardless of how many attacks they got or if they already used that weapon before in the same turn (releasing a grapple is a free action).

The *rules as written* say that, if the creature cannot make a *Free Action*, it cannot make that free grapple. Meaning you couldn't use grab with [Attacks of Opportunity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity), since you cannot make *free actions* outside your turn. But you can still do it if you are [staggered](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Staggered), for instance, since you are still allowed *free actions*.

However, this [FAQ item](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9shq) changes that ruling so it is allowed:

> While you can’t take most free actions off your turn, **Grab**, Trip, Pull, Push, and Rock Catching’s free actions can all be used off-turn. This will be reflected in future errata.

Comment: Paizo FAQ'd grab to work on Attacks of Opportunity. See http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9shq

Comment: *This will be reflected in future errata.* which never saw daylight. But thanks for the link.

Comment: Good luck, *FAQ*, trying to adjudicate that! (Same boat as attacks of opportunity being free actions—yuck!—according to the *Melee Tactics Toolbox*.)